# prevent post to have multiple categories in my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, categories

I'm writing a plugin, I want to prevent posts have multiple categories *(i.e same product having category "Samsung" & "Apple")*. Any idea on how to use some actions/filters to achieve this using my plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. What this would do is convert the category taxonomy checkboxes to radio buttons. In this way only one category can be selected.

```
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', 'wpse_64691_one_category_only', '', 2);
function wpse_64691_one_category_only( $args, $post_id){
    $args['walker'] = new WPSE_64691_Category_Radio;
    return $args;
}

class WPSE_64691_Category_Radio extends Walker {
    var $tree_type = 'category';
    var $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id'); //TODO: decouple this

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent<ul class='children'>\n";
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args, $id = 0 ) {
            extract($args);
            if ( empty($taxonomy) )
                    $taxonomy = 'category';

            if ( $taxonomy == 'category' )
                    $name = 'post_category';
            else
                    $name = 'tax_input['.$taxonomy.']';

            $class = in_array( $category->term_id, $popular_cats ) ? ' class="popular-category"' : '';
            if ( $taxonomy == 'category' )
                $output .= "\n<li id='{$taxonomy}-{$category->term_id}'$class>" . '<label class="selectit"><input value="' . $category->term_id . '" type="radio" name="'.$name.'[]" id="in-'.$taxonomy.'-' . $category->term_id . '"' . checked( in_array( $category->term_id, $selected_cats ), true, false ) . disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), false, false ) . ' /> ' . esc_html( apply_filters('the_category', $category->name )) . '</label>';
            else
                $output .= "\n<li id='{$taxonomy}-{$category->term_id}'$class>" . '<label class="selectit"><input value="' . $category->term_id . '" type="checkbox" name="'.$name.'[]" id="in-'.$taxonomy.'-' . $category->term_id . '"' . checked( in_array( $category->term_id, $selected_cats ), true, false ) . disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), false, false ) . ' /> ' . esc_html( apply_filters('the_category', $category->name )) . '</label>';
    }

    function end_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are jquery plugins that change category checkboxes to radio buttons [Making category selection radio buttons](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/making-category-selection-radio-buttons). This however is not a pure safe solution. What you can do is using

```
add_action('publish_post', 'your_function');
```

Do a var_dump in you function to see what is actually going on. Then you will also see if there are more than on category checked.

```
function your_function($content){
  var_dump($content);

  //Check if more than one category is checked, return false and don't publish
}
```

You can also look at: [Running a function in Wordpress when publishing a custom post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441543/running-a-function-in-wordpress-when-publishing-a-custom-post-type)